# Contexts in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, function

I have a basic doubt.
If the rspec file contains many contexts:

```
describe Name do
context "number1" do
.......
.......
end
context "number 2" do
.......
.......
end
context "number 3" do
.......
.......
end
```

How should the functions from each of the contexts be described in the .rb file? Should they be in the same class or different class? Is there any book I can read to improve my knowledge about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The structure I use when defining rspec files (based on reading I've done on rspec) is that you use `describes` to describe specific functions, and `context` to talk about a specific context of state and/or path through the function.

Example class:

```
class MyClass
    def self.my_class_method(bool)
        if bool == true
            return "Yes"
        else
            return "No"
        end
    end

    def my_instance_method
        today = Date.today
        if today.month == 2 and today.day == 14
            puts "Valentine's Day"
        else
            puts "Other"
        end
     end
end
```

As you can see, I've defined a class method and an instance method that do really silly and random functions. But the point is this: the class method will do something different based on the argument, and the instance method will do something different based on some outside factor: you need to test all these, and these are different *contexts*. But we will *describe* the functions in the rspec file.

Rspec file:

```
describe MyClass do
    describe ".my_class_method" do
        context "with a 'true' argument" do
            it "returns 'Yes'." do
                MyClass.my_class_method(true).should eq "Yes"
            end
        end

        context "with a 'false' argument" do
            it "returns 'No'." do
                MyClass.my_class_method(false).should eq "No"
            end
        end
    end

    describe "#my_instance_method" do
        context "on Feb 14" do
            it "returns 'Valentine's Day'." do
                Date.stub(:today) { Date.new(2012,2,14) }
                MyClass.new.my_instance_method.should eq "Valentine's Day"
            end
        end

        context "on a day that isn't Feb 14" do
            it "returns 'Other'." do
                Date.stub(:today) { Date.new(2012,2,15) }
                MyClass.new.my_instance_method.should eq "Other"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So you can see the `describe` is for saying what method you're describing, and matches up with the name of a method in your class. The `context` is used to evaluate different conditions the method can be called in, or different states that affect the way the method works.

Hope this helps!